# Toggle mobile navigation and adress data

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, navigation, toggle

Sup guys,

for a while now I have been trying to get this to work in jQuery, but I have no idea how to accomplish that.
It's about the mobile navigation of a basic website.
Basically I am trying to achieve that the mobile navigation closes if we click on the 3 dots with the adress data and the other way around. You can see it in this example:

https://www.templatemonster.com/de/demo/62436.html
Choose the mobile version to see what I mean.

Does anyone know how to do this with jQuery or javascript?
Here is what I have currently:

```
Adress Data

$('.js--adress-icon').click(function() {
        var kont = $('.js--adress-nav');

        kont.slideToggle(200);
});

Mobile Navigation

var hamburger = $('#hamburger-icon');

hamburger.click(function() {
        var nav = $('.js--main-nav');
        nav.slideToggle(200);
        hamburger.toggleClass('active');
        return false;
});

if ($(window).width() < 768){
        $('.main-navigation li a').on('click', function(){
            $('.js--main-nav').hide();
            $('#hamburger-icon').removeClass('active');
        });
};
```

Thx in advance!

Comment: have you done something already. If yes post the code here for us to help

Comment: I added th code hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your html looks like but this is a simple way to achieve this using css and javascript

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

```
<nav class="menu">
  <ul class="active">
    <li class="current-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu2</a></li>
  </ul>

  <a class="toggle-nav" href="#">&#8285;</a>
</nav>
</body>
```

then your javascript

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.toggle-nav').click(function(e) {
      jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
      jQuery('.menu ul').toggleClass('active');

      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

then your css

```
 /*----- Toggle Button -----*/

  /*----- Menu -----*/
  @media screen and (min-width: 860px) {
    .menu {
      width:100%;
      padding:10px 18px;
      box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
      border-radius:3px;
      background:#303030;
    }
  }

  .menu ul {
    display:inline-block;
  }

  .menu li {
    margin:0px 50px 0px 0px;
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    font-size:17px;
  }

  .menu li:last-child {
    margin-right:0px;
  }

  .menu a {
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color:#777;
    transition:color linear 0.15s;
  }

  .menu a:hover, .menu .current-item a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#66a992;
  }
  /*----- Responsive -----*/
  @media screen and (max-width: 1150px) {
    .wrap {
      width:90%;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 970px) {
    .search-form input {
      width:120px;
    }
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 860px) {
    .menu {
      position:relative;
      display:inline-block;
    }

    .menu ul.active {
      display:none;
    }

    .menu ul {
      width:100%;
      position:absolute;
      top:120%;
      left:0px;
      padding:10px 18px;
      box-shadow:0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
      border-radius:3px;
      background:#303030;
    }

    .menu ul:after {
      width:0px;
      height:0px;
      position:absolute;
      top:0%;
      left:22px;
      content:'';
      transform:translate(0%, -100%);
      border-left:7px solid transparent;
      border-right:7px solid transparent;
      border-bottom:7px solid #303030;
    }

    .menu li {
      margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;
      float:none;
      display:block;
    }

    .menu a {
      display:block;
    }

    .toggle-nav {
      padding:20px;
      float:left;
      color:#777;
      font-size:20px;
    }

    .toggle-nav:hover, .toggle-nav.active {
      text-decoration:none;
      color:#66a992;
    }
```

}

check this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wggs8pf8/

Comment: I meant something else, here is what i have right now, I hope you kinda get the idea https://codepen.io/nickmeister/pen/zPgbgG The other one is supposed to close when one of them opens and the other one ist alrdy open. In my mind the code I wrote is correct, but I can't get it to work. Do you have any idea what is missing/wrong?